# Design a server app without long life object in .Net?

Tags: .net, caching

I have a game server project using .Net 4.0. I'm using MemoryCache class and caching many object that can be modified by multiple users at same time for quick i/o and synchronization. Recently after the game has been published, I found there's problem to my design. Because these cached object are long life objects, they all go to GC gen 2, and hard to be deallocated, so gen 2 heap goes very big (~ 8 Gigabytes after 5 days) and take too long for a full GC.

After days of googling, I think maybe it's the best way not using long life objects to avoid big gen 2 heap. But I don't know what to do. These objects are loaded from db, modified by user request, and save back to db, and they are too complicated to serialize to byte[] to save in memcached, even they can be serialize, (read from memcached -> modify -> write back) is not a thread safe operation too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But if system needs more memory, it will go through all GC levels. It seems as if your cache is simply too big.

Comment: In fact I just want to find a way to avoid using long life objects. Consumed over 5GB of memory, yeah, that's a big cache, but the real problem is they are all in gen 2 and cause big stop while gc.

Comment: Have you tried using [Server GC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clyon/archive/2004/09/08/226981.aspx)?  This splits the heap up into multiple heaps (one per processor) which are collected in parallel in order to improve throughput.

Comment: Nice suggestions for you all, thanks. I found several badly designed classes recently and after i modified them, memory usage drop to less than 2 Gigabytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a couple of suggestions

- Firstly have you tried using [Server GC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clyon/archive/2004/09/08/226981.aspx) This splits the heap up into multiple heaps (one per processor) which are collected in parallel in order to improve throughput on multiple processor machines.  This might help solve your problem outright.
- If this doesn't help and your gen 2 heap is still taking too long to collect then you should consider using some sort of external caching framework (like Memcached).  Without knowing more specifics this would probably be my preferred approach.
- Alternatively you could consider using an [object pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) and re-purposing existing objects rather than allocating and deallocating new ones.

The only other solutions I can think of are things like [redirecting to another server server when a full GC is about to happen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/05/29/background-garbage-collection-in-clr-4-0.aspx) (notification of when a full GC is about to happen is a .Net 3.5 SP1 feature) however this is likely to be more complicated than the above second option.

Comment: Thanks, but we are using Server GC right now. Since our servers are win2k3 boxes so no 4.5 Server + Concurrent GC available.

Comment: @Sylphia How about the other suggestions?

Comment: And you are meaning load balancing... We haven't planned using load balancing at the beginning, so current architecture cannot support cross server state synchronization. It's not a big project from the beginning. Web games are usually mean making quick money, we can't make it big and heavy. Currently we have 40k users, of which 1-2k simultaneously online. I'm refactoring classes to structs, hope this can do some good.

Comment: Object pool, sounds good, but it's nearly impossible to implement that currently. But I'll definitely using object pool in my next project.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why this server has to cache everything locally in memory? If you are connecting from server to database I can understand why you will be having such issues and why you cache them in memory. However there are plenty of caching frameworks which would work across multiple application instances such as Memcached.

Granted it would not be as quick as having it in memory, but is there actually a performance issue around retrieving objects, or did you just pre-empt there being speed problems and pre-optimise? As if you have then you may find that if you scale your application horizontally and stop caching in memory and push the responsibility to another system you may have each server instance being slightly slower but it would be a lot easier and quicker to scale.

Comment: Most caching products need my objects to be serialized either to byte[] or string and our objects are too complex to be serialized.

Comment: There are plenty of frameworks which can handle complex object trees and serialization. http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344 Shows some of them, MongoDB may be good. Unfortunately if your architecture does not support stateless communication so you cannot really scale it horizontally and your boxes cache is filling up to fast when in memory, then there is no solution, you have a set amount of memory and too much going in there... you could maybe do as one of the other posters says and try clearing your cache a bit more frequently, but its going to be more work for little gain.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to configure a life time for cached objects? May be there is no need to store so many objects that aren't used N hours/days.

When it doesn't help, you need to change your caching mechanism. Also when you need to store so huge amount of objects and so long time, then you need more then one server. You can use on-premise hosting or cloud, for both of them, there is caching mechanism called Distributed Cache. On premise for .NET it could be AppFabric Cache, in cloud using Windows Azure - also pretty similar to AppFabric.

So my suggestion to you when life time doesn't help then use distributed cache in cloud (Windows Azure, Amazon AWS) or on-premise (AppFabric)

Comment: I've never working with cloud services :P...  These objects are loaded from db, keeping data through user session, they expired after user logoff.

Comment: It could be also used with on-premise hosting. Why object are long live? How long is user session?

Comment: Why you think it's a caching? How many memory take user sessions?